# How to get a scalar value from Mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using Node.js, express and Mysql. The app is to report incidents at work. I generate a reference number for each new incident incrementally for each year in the format 2023_01, 2023_02, and so on. I have a stored procedure which returns the number of incidents for a particular year, but I am struggling to get that value in node.js.

My stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE Read_IncidentYearCount_SP
    (
        IN YearP INT
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(IncidentDate) FROM Incidents AS Cnt
    WHERE YEAR(IncidentDate) = YearP;
        
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

My app.js code snippet:

```
const year = new Date().getFullYear();
console.log('Year = ' + year);

const dataYear = [
    year
]

const sqlYear = `CALL Read_IncidentYearCount_SP(?)`;
const [yearMeta] = await mysqldb.pool.query(sqlYear, dataYear);
let count = yearMeta[0];

count += 1;

console.log('Result = ' + count);
const refNo = GetReferenceNumber(count);


function GetReferenceNumber(count) {
    const dateNow = new Date();
    const year = dateNow.getFullYear();

    if (count < 10) {
        return ('' + year + '_0' + count);
    } else {
        return ('' + year + '_' + count);
    }
}
```

Currently the value of count is [object]. I have also tried:

```
let count = yearMeta[0][0];
let count = yearMeta[0][''];
```

I changed from stored procedure to just a select statement, but I am still unable to get the scalar value from the query. I tried the following:

```
const sqlYear = `SELECT COUNT(IncidentDate) FROM Incidents AS Cnt WHERE YEAR(IncidentDate) = ?;`;
const yearMeta = await mysqldb.pool.query(sqlYear, dataYear);

console.log('yearMeta[0] = ' + yearMeta[0][0]);
console.log('yearMeta[1] = ' + yearMeta[1][0]);
```

Both these console.logs yield [object Object], but I am unable to get information from these objects.

Comment: A query returns a rowset, even when this rowset contains one row of one column. You must receive this rowset, get its first (current) row then retrieve needed column's value from it by the name or physical posession. If a query calls stored procedure then it may receive not single rowset but a collection of rowsets, so you need to select the former rowset from this collection additionally.

Comment: Log the object without appending it to a string `console.log(yearMeta)`. If that still doesn't show you the complete object, use `util`. `console.log(util.inspect(yearMeta, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))`